# Can I change the resolution of a display in recovery mode?

Tags: macos, terminal, mac-mini, recovery, resolution

Booted to High Sierra recovery HD, I’m not able to open the system preferences and choose a different resolution.

Can terminal be used from the utilities menu to change the resolution?

I have a Mac mini and Emerson TV connected over HDMI cable.

Comment: Please edit the question to add additional details (there is a link for this at the bottom of the text), adding a comment doesn't help. Editing the question will place it into the review queue for reopenings.

Comment: This is censorship. Stop please.

Comment: @M3553N63R I’ve cleared all the comments except for the one needed to move this forward and yours equating moderation with censorship. Have a look at the edit control and the tour in help for how to get this temporary hold released. Your call to action of **“Please reply and share”** is an excellent thing for a discussion forum, it’s the opposite of what we do here. That’s why the hold to let you or someone else to edit the main post is correct.

Comment: Does that edit help you? Hopefully I captured your objective question correctly. I voted +1 to help get this back on track

Comment: Oh great(sarcastic), censorship,  judgment, post editorship. And your bs answers is... (drum rolls)..."NO"....!

Comment: Sorry I wasn’t able to help. You are free to edit again or roll back my edits. I’m not trying to be sarcastic or judgemental. More than three people had issues with your post, so please don’t shoot the volunteer messengers about close reasons.

Comment: First off, let me speak my thoughts...."be used from the utilities menu"?....its called recovery mode. Secondly, I been knowing I can use terminal in recovery mode to change resolution. Thirdly, that's why I asked "how" not "can I"....plus pressing shift key to boot into safe mode (which doesn't work for in my opinion 90% of mac os x owners), and forthly...I know I can Change resolution in terminal because I must (because the mac gives me only one choice if I want to keep and not lose my computer accounts and all apps, and files), and 6th thing is, I requested answers (terminal command lines)!

Comment: Reason why I decided to skip safe mode and do what the big error message on front of black screen that told me to change resolution because it said tv does not support output format, video resolution and refresh rate plus message after that told me resolution mismatch change device's resolution. And join here getting censored by people who don't have answers. Dude everybody should know they can use terminal in recovery mode to change mac computer resolution and they actually know they can. Why edit my post and put "can terminal be used from the utilities menu to change the resolution"?!